# Big issue with IBAction in custom class called from a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibaction

I have the following code, which I have put together because I just don't understand the logs I'm getting. I originally had a nib-file from where I had an action connected to one of the buttons. the code would never change the view as Im trying, so I tried to connect the button by tag instead and just adding a method for a tap event. Now take note that the two methods are identical, the difference is only the way they are connected (both methods get called). But in the IBAction method sunPushed currentVC is NULL (logs posted below, but you get the point), even though its equivalent regular method holds the reference correctly. Can somebody please shed any light on the subject, it's been bugging me all day that I can't figure out why this is happening. Any help is greatly appreciated! (I've been thinking theres some difference in how the compiler treats an IBAction vs reg. method)

headerfile:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FooterViewTest1 : UIView
//@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *button1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *currentVC;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;

-(void)buttonPushed;
-(void)initButtons:(UIViewController *)viewController;
@end
```

implementation

```
#import "FooterViewTest1.h"
#import "StartViewController.h"

@implementation FooterViewTest1

-(void)initButtons:(UIViewController *)viewController{

/*UIButton *button1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 180)];
[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_bar_sun_black"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPushed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[viewController.view addSubview:button1];*/
self.currentVC = viewController;

NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RaymioFooterView" owner:nil options:nil];
UIView *footerView = [viewController.view viewWithTag:1];
UIView *footerViewContent = [nibContents lastObject];
NSLog(@"SELFinside initbuttons%@", self);
NSLog(@"currentVCinside initbuttons%@", self.currentVC);

UIButton *button1X = (UIButton *)[footerViewContent viewWithTag:5];
[button1X addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPushed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[footerView addSubview:footerViewContent];
}

- (IBAction)sunPushed{
NSLog(@"SELFinside sunpushed%@", self);
NSLog(@"currentVCinside sunpushed%@", self.currentVC);
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
StartViewController *startViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StartViewController"];
[self.currentVC presentViewController:startViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)buttonPushed{
NSLog(@"SELFinside buttonpushed%@", self);
NSLog(@"currentVCinside buttonpushed%@", self.currentVC);
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
StartViewController *startViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StartViewController"];
[self.currentVC presentViewController:startViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

see the below image

[image]

Thanks again!

Initialising footerView:

```
 self.footerViewTest = [FooterViewTest1 new];
//self.footerViewTest.currentVC = self;
[self.footerViewTest initButtons:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing -- but in your logs `self` is two different objects: 1 object at address 0x...6f0 inside `buttonPushed` and `initButtons` and another at address 0x...b90 inside `sunPushed`. Can you show the whole class?

EDIT:

Your problem is that the IBAction is being set via Storyboard and the view is being created via a call to `new`. To use the action as defined in your storyboard instead of doing:

```
self.footerViewTest = [FooterViewTest1 new];
```

attach the property to the view in storyboard. That way you will have the same (single!) instance in your code.

Comment: yea I see what you are saying. That is my whole FooterView class. All I do from my VC(s) is call new on my property footerView, then call initButtons: on that property. Hence my frustration its not working right with IBAction, since I deliberately copied the ibaction, put that in a new method and then manually add touch event to the button, just to make sure I wasn't going insane. Seems like something is going on..

Comment: And currentVC is an IBOutlet connected in storyboard?

Comment: No its just a property of the FooterView class. CurrentVC is set to the view controller thats initialising footerView class and calls initButtons:self.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problems there. Can you show the class that currentVC is an instance of? Is it possible that your footer view has a weak reference to self.currentVC..? If you can give me a bit more context I may be able to help a little more. Or even if you want to pack up your project and put it on github I can have a look there

Comment: I edited my post in incl. my header file. currentVC is obv just an instance of UIViewController as it is set to the parameter "viewcontroller" that initButtons: take. I am not that solid on iOS yet myself, but Ive also had another developer look at it, and we have just accepted the facts that it won't work with the connection by IBAction. Even though interface builder creates another object different from the one generated when doing it programmatically I still don't see why currentVC would be NULL in either one. I will ask if I can upload the project but Im not sure client will like it

Comment: I imagine you are creating a new instance of FooterViewTest1 in whatever piece of code is calling these methods. When using the IBAction, it's using the instance created by IB, therefore you have 2 instances. That's all I can think of with the amount of code there. Perhaps show the code that creates/initialises/talks to FooterViewTest1.

Comment: Well yea that seems to be the problem somehow. But I was originally working only with IB, and it wasn't working, therefore I tried to add the touch event programmatically (I put my initialising in my post, but its only 2 lines of code..)

Comment: Yes, but the IBAction is set to the view in IB, which is a completely different view instance than the one you created by calling new

Comment: Sry for late reply, was out for the weekend. I tried commenting out self.footerViewTest = [FooterViewTest1 new]; and instead I made an IBOutlet (in my view controller presenting the footer). I get the same result even though I see what you're trying to point out. The programmatically initialising with new has been commented out, so I have no idea why its still making 2 objects. Thanks for your time though, very much appreciated. Maybe I should just stick with whats working and give up on trying to understand Xcode's voodoo...? (though I hate that)

Comment: obv I connected the outlet in the view controller thats needs the footer added (and not between my xib and the class). I suppose this is correct, also because it was in the view controller that I created the footer by using [... new];